# Automatically add a single menu item of an add-in in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I am using Microsoft Excel 2010 for Windows.

I have already developed an add-in `addin.xlam`, which contains a sub `main`. `addin.xlam` is at the right place so that it is visible and selectable via the menu `Developer -> Add-Ins`. When I open a normal workbook `test.xlsm`, and press `Alt + F11`, I can see the code of `addin.xlam` is loaded.

My aim is to add a single menu item to the menu bar of Excel, to allow users to launch `main` of `add-in.xlam`. By following this [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm), my code in `addin.xlam` is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Dim cControl As CommandBarButtonPrivate
Sub Workbook_AddinInstall()
    On Error Resume Next 'Just in case

    'Delete any existing menu item that may have been left.
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Super Code").Delete

    'Add the new menu item and Set a CommandBarButton Variable to it
    Set cControl = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.Add

    'Work with the Variable
    With cControl
        .Caption = "Super Code"
        .Style = msoButtonCaption
        .OnAction = "main" 'Macro stored in a Standard Module
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_AddinUninstall()
    On Error Resume Next 'In case it has already gone.
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Super Code").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

This code is well placed in `ThisWorkbook` of `addin.xlam`, it is also visible in `test.xlsm`. **But I can't see any change in the menu bar.**

Does anyone know what happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The AddinInstall and AddinUninstall events are only fired when the the addin is "installed" or "uninstalled" using the Excel Addin Manager.

IMHO this can lead to problems, so I always recommend using the Workbook_Open and Workbook_BeforeClose events instead.

Comment: Agreed. I use this method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Charles is right, you need to replace `Workbook_AddinInstall()` with `Workbook_Open()`, and replace `Workbook_AddinUninstall()` with `Workbook_BeforeClose()`.

furthermore, you need `CommandBarButton` not `CommandBarButtonPrivate`.

good luck!